# Execution failed for task mockableAndroidJar, mockable-android- . jar already exists

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I am facing issue with Android Studio 3, gradle android plugin 3 with build target 27 and support lib 27.0.0

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':module:mockableAndroidJar'.
> Output file [[...]/build/generated/mockable-android-27.v3.jar] already exists.
```

I have to clean or manually delete all mockable-android  jars from the generated folder time to time. So this means instead of getting better build times, I have to clean the project most of the times.

Comment: can you add your gradle files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply cleanup the existing jar before running the task again. Running `clean`does work, but it's a little intense in my opinion. Instead, make the android-generated task depend on a very specific cleanup task:

```
task cleanAndroidMock(type: Delete) {
    description = 'Deletes the mockable Android jar'

    delete fileTree("${project.buildDir}/generated") {
        include 'mockable-android*.jar'
    }
}

project.afterEvaluate {
    tasks['mockableAndroidJar'].dependsOn cleanAndroidMock
}
```

Comment: This worked for me! Not sure why the task doesn't do it in the first place, if it complains when the file is already there.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue. Although, with API 28 platform tools. I deleted from the path and reinstalled, which worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue as well as I'm using a modified android.jar (which has all the hidden API revealed).
I don't use the unit testing and there's no apparent way to disable it in Android Studio 2.2.2, so I found a workaround for this problem:

Go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler
Add to "Command-line Options":
-x :app:prepareReleaseUnitTestDependencies -x :app:mockableAndroidJar -x :app:compileReleaseUnitTestSources
Press "OK" and try to Rebuild Project again.
Now the unit testing compilation tasks will always be skipped and no errors will be thrown.

Comment: Using Android Studio 3.2, an unhidden API android.jar, I come across this too. `Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:androidApis'.` `Failed to transform file 'android.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-mockable-jar, returnDefaultValues=false} using transform MockableJarTransform`

Comment: @Weekend did you found any solution for this error message? I'm updating Android Studio to 3.2 too, and breaking my balls with the same error... :(

Comment: @jcasadellaoller I change to AOSP android.jar, Gradle sync the project, and wait for the indexing completed. After that, change back to custom android.jar, and the project compiles. I hope this also works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Finally, we roll back the version of the com.android.tools.build:gradle: from 3.2.1 to 3.1.1. The build synck works correctly now... We will wait for newer versions and try it again!

Answer (score 0):

Try going to menu: Build -> Clean Project. 
Or you can try menu: Files -> Invalidade Caches/Restart 
Both worked for me!

Comment: Or you can just delete one file. But I'm not going to do either every build.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to navigate to the given path `[[...]/build/generated/mockable-android-27.v3.jar]` and simply remove the file `mockable-android-27.v3.jar`.Go back to android studio and build again.