# Task with name 'mockableAndroidJar' not found in project ':app'

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

after changing gradle android plugin version to 3.2.1

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

I received such build error:

```
Task with name 'mockableAndroidJar' not found in project ':app'.
```

Invalidate cache and restart doesn't help

Comment: Have you tried any of the things listed in this thread ? https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api/issues/21

Comment: @VincentD. thanks, it doesn't work

Comment: This one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47051813/execution-failed-for-task-mockableandroidjar-mockable-android-jar-already-ex

Comment: @VincentD. nope. sorry, i will remove gradle android sdk and android studio and install it again. I'm so tired of this game called "find the right version code to make a successful build

Answer (score 7):

Happened to me too, fixed by upgrading Android Studio to version 3.2.1

Seems like they've changed the gradle task name from `mockableAndroidJar` to `createMockableJar`

Comment: thanks. but in my case the problem was with pitest. It's a third party mechanism for testing. When i removed pitest everything is working.